# Solutions to problems from Algorithms Jeff Erickson

Tags: algorithms

Do you know of any website or other source with partial/complete solutions to problems from Algorithms book of Jeff Erickson?

Comment: The author has decided not to publish solutions. See [here](http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/hwex.html#solutions).

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes a publisher will provide an answer key, but only to people it is pretty sure are educators. You might write to either an author or the publisher to see what is available.

But that book was published by the author, so contact him for information. I suspect there is a web site.